# C#, Forms, DataGridView. Unexpected Visible behaviour

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, hide, visible

I working on application with DataGridView.
It contains several tabs, each tab includes a DataGridView of some parameters.
I need implement Admin and User modes, where each grid table
should hide some rows according to the mode.
I have a problem with the hiding: **on some tabs the hiding work perfect on other doesn't work absolutely**.
I did some tests: hid all rows of problematic grid, printed Visible values after delay. 
used`grid.CurrentCell = null`.
I didn't found any mistake that point to the reason of the problem.
I use the same method for all:

```
private void HideParameter(DataGridView grid, string ParamName)
{
    CurrencyManager CM = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[grid.DataSource];
    CM.SuspendBinding();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string Val = grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (Val.Contains(ParamName))
        {
            //grid.CurrentCell = null;
            grid.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }
    CM.ResumeBinding();
}
```

Grid binding:

```
void BindGridWithDataSource(DataTable dt, DataGridView grid)
{
  BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
  bs.DataSource = dt;
  grid.DataSource = bs;
}
```

<br[image: Picture of the tabs]>

Comment: What is the grid bound to?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a `CurrencyManager` directly. Bind via a `BindingSource` and then access everything related to data binding through it, including the `SuspendBinding` method, should you actually need it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I do not understand your recommendation

Comment: The whole point of a `BindingSource` is to be a one-stop-shop for all things binding. It groups functionality previously found in multiple different places, including the `CurrencyManager` class. Don't bother getting a `CurrencyManager`. Just call `SuspendBinding` on the `BindingSource`. Also, don't create the `BindingSource` in code. Add it in the designer, just like a control. Then it's easy to access anywhere.

Comment: As for the issue, get rid of all that code. You have a `DataTable` bound to a `BindingSource`. Just set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` appropriately and that will handle the filtering.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, with `Visible` is much simpler to manage tab view. More of that, my code uses "hidden" grid rows. If I will use `Filter` , my code can not access to filtered DataTable entries.

Comment: Of course your code can still access those `DataRows`. They still exist. You can access them via the `BindingSource` or the grid but they are still in the `DataTable`. You should learn how `DataTables` and `DataViews` work. And no, it's not simpler. Filtering via the `BindingSource` is a single line of code. In what universe is your multiple lines of code simpler than that? You can do whatever you want but it seems that the reasons you want to do it are simply not reasons at all.

Comment: I have tabs with ~20 rows. With `Visible` I can hide all and show only 1-2 rows. Or vose versa, to show all rows except 1-2 (according to User/Admin mode). With`Filter` I need create string of `OR`s and cannot do either *show* or *hide* approach

Comment: You're wrong but I'm not gaining anything by arguing the point so I'm out.